# Android Button.setError() does not show overlay with error text

Tags: android

I'm working on a little App right now where I want to disable a Button if some requirements are not met. To show the user why the Button is disabled I want to display an error icon and some text via the `setError()` method like you do on an EditText.

The Problem is: the error drawable is there but an overlay with the error text is missing.

Calling `requestFocus()` on the Button right after setError() does not solve the problem.
Calling setError() on a disabled or enabled button does not change anything either.

Here are some excerpts of my code:

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/minWidth"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/myErrorBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/stdButtonPadding"
            android:text="ErrorBtn"
            android:textSize="@dimen/stdButtonTextSize" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

```java
(Button)findViewById(R.id.myErrorBtn)).setError("Not enabled because...");
```

Since my reputation is to low I leave you with links instead of pictures to illustrate the problem.

[image: This is what I get]

[image: This is what I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i figured this out.
I was pretty confident that `Button.setError()` should work as expected because `Button` extends `TextView`.
From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)) for `TextView.setError()`:

> [...] sets an error message that will be displayed in a popup when the TextView **has focus** [...]

This and Padmini's answer led me to the solution.
Setting  `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` **on the Button** did the trick.

Comment: also need to call button.requestFocus()

Answer (score 0):

Set Error is meant to show an input error in the EditText, not on a button. If you want to show Error on some requirement not met then Show a Toast or dialog something.

Answer (score 0):

SetError is used for showing errors on Edittexts. If you want to achieve the layout you have shown in the example image you can do something like this.

```
<LinearLayout>
 <Button>
 </Button>
 <TextView> //Set error on this text when your criteria is not matched.
 </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Zeerak suggested change your button to textview and add a button style to mimic button, also add focusable="true

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myErrorBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:padding="@dimen/stdButtonPadding"
            android:text="ErrorBtn"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/stdButtonTextSize" />
```

Then in code do like

```
Textview textview=findViewById(R.id.myErrorBtn);
textview.setError("Not enabled because...");
```